# Using Pandas, How to replace the last word of the string with an empty strings without distorting rest of the string?

Tags: python, pandas

I can't share the actual data. So I am taking an example. 
Suppose I have a list of suffixes -

```
Suffix_List = ["Ltd.", "Inc.", "Limited", "Corp.", "AG"]
```

I have a data frame with a column containing company names. I want to replace the suffixes of the company name with an empty string. This should not distort the rest of company name. For example: Say the company name is "CAGE AG". "AG" should just be removed from the suffix not from the company name. So the result should be just "CAGE". Also, suffix should only be removed if it is present in the Suffix_List.

Right now I am using -

```
for suffix in Suffix_List:
    df['company_name'] = df['company_name'].str.replace( suffix,"")
```

But this distorts the actual company name too.

Sample company names could be - CAGE AG, Wage Limited, Tage Ltd. , Sage Inc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to substitute out the suffix:

```
In [11]: re.sub("\s?(" + "|".join(Suffix_List) + ")$", "", "CAGE AG")
Out[11]: 'CAGE'
```

*This looks whether any (`|`) of the suffixes ends (`$`) the string.*

On the Series/column you can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame([["CAGE AG"], ["Stack Exchange Inc."]], columns=["company"])

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
          company
0            CAGE
1  Stack Exchange

In [23]: df["company"] = df["company"].str.replace("\s?(" + "|".join(Suffix_List) + ")$", "")

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
          company
0            CAGE
1  Stack Exchange
```

Comment: How do we add a condition to : df["company"] = df["company"].str.replace("\s?(" + "|".join(Suffix_List) + ")$", "")
so that it does not distort single word companies. For example -  The company name is "ZINC". It would not be correct to remove INC from here because then the company name left would only be "Z" which is wrong.

Comment: @user6461192 perhaps the space could be required? e.g. with `\s+` at the beginning rather than `\s?`

Comment: Thanks. It did work. It will be great if you could tell me the meaning of the regex used in words. df["company"] = df["company"].str.replace("\s?(" + "|".join(Suffix_List) + ")$", "")

Comment: I have another similar question for you. I have two frames. One has company name and other has domain name. Domain name is sometimes empty for few companies. s = s.to_frame()
s.columns=['company_name']
s1 = s1.to_frame()
s1.columns=['domain']. I want to merge both of them to another frame. But while doing so, the matching between domains and company names is wrong.                         x = pd.merge(3rdFrame, s, left_index=True, right_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)
y = pd.merge(x, s1, left_index=True, right_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: @user6461192 please ask as a new question. The formatting will be better, and it'll get more people who can look at it (not just me). :)

Comment: I understand. But I am a new user here and I have to wait for 2 days before I ask a new question. I am so sorry for the formatting thing. Because there is a limit to words I can write in a comment.

Comment: @user6461192 it sounds like a join http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-on-index ( I recommend reading that entire page carefully ). It's unclear how you want to match them from your question!